# Using Vue :is prop for dynamic components passed via config object

Tags: vue.js

I have a confirmation popup Vue component with a config object like so:

```
{
  title: null,
  message: null,
  onConfirm: null,
  onDismiss: null,
  modal_class: null,
  icon: null,
  confirmBtnText: null,
  confirmBtnColor: null,
  component: null
}
```

In the template I want to have a "dynamic" component rendered here:

```
<component class="component-container" :is="component"></component>
```

I am initializing the component passed in like so:

```
import {CarrierSaferInfo} from './path/to/single-file-component.vue'
let SaferInfo = Vue.extend(CarrierSaferInfo)
let SaferComp = new SaferInfo({
  propsData: {
    carrier,
    dom_class: 'text-white',
  }
})
openConfirmDialog({
  //...other props
  component: SaferComp
})
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
```

Edit:
I've tried now to use the actual `$options` object of the component after it is extended like so:

```
<component class="component-container" :is="component.$options"></component>
```

In the component definition the prop `carrier` is required. Event though in the `$options` object it shows that the `carrier` prop inside `propsData` is an object, it is still saying:

```
Missing required prop: carrier
```

So, making progress but now the `propsData` is not populating in the render function for some reason.

Comment: i don't think you can bind the 'is' attribute to a div element ... have you tried this : <component :is="component"></component>

Comment: @SirDad I just tried that and it gives the same error

Comment: I am not familiar the way you are initialising it but `:is`  takes `string` so `:is='SaferInfo'`

Comment: @SatyamPathak the reason I am initializing the component that way is because the props need changed on each initialization of the component. From the docs the `:is` prop will take either the name (your suggestion) or the component options object (necessary for my example)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `v-bind` rather than `is`. You can include `is` within a `v-bind` if you want to keep it all as one object.

```js
const CarrierSaferInfo = {
  props: {
    dom_class: String,

    carrier: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },

  template: '<div :class="dom_class">{{ carrier }}</div>'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      component: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.component = {
        is: CarrierSaferInfo,
        carrier: 'hello',
        dom_class: 'text-white'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="onClick">Open</button>
  <component v-if="component" v-bind="component" />
</div>
```

It is important to note that I've got rid of `SaferInfo`, `SaferComp` and any mention of `Vue.extend` or `new`. Where I've got `this.component = ...` you'd probably need to use something like this instead:

```js
openConfirmDialog({
    // ... other props ...
    component: {
        is: CarrierSaferInfo,
        carrier,
        dom_class: 'text-white'
    }
})
```

It can be made to work with `is`. Not sure if there's a more direct way of doing this but a wrapper component can provide a `render` function that sets the props. e.g.:

```js
const CarrierSaferInfo = {
  props: {
    dom_class: String,

    carrier: {
      required: true,
      type: String
    }
  },

  template: '<div :class="dom_class">{{ carrier }}</div>'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      component: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.component = {
        render(h) {
          return h(CarrierSaferInfo, {
            props: {
              carrier: 'howdy',
              dom_class: 'text-white'
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="onClick">Open</button>
  <component v-if="component" :is="component" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! This worked beautifully...not sure why it's not mentioned in the Dynamic Components section of the docs. I just did `<component v-if="component" v-bind="component" />`

Comment: Disregard last comment - it didn't work. I needed this: `<component :is="component.$options" v-bind="component.$options.propsData" />`

Comment: @MikeHarrison That suggests you're still barking up the wrong tree. You shouldn't need to go anywhere near `$options` or `propsData`. I've added a little more explanation below my first example to try to clarify how it applies to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle - I've changed it to `<component :is="component" v-bind="componentProps" />` with another config option for `openConfirmDialog()`

Answer (score 0):

This looks rather relevant: https://top10webjs.com/2019/02/02/vue-js-passing-props-dynamically-to-dynamic-component-in-vuejs/

```
<component :is=”currentComponent” v-bind=”currentProperties”></component>
```

Via the syntax here :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object